# Происхождение ругательства "Сволочи"

Tags: этимология

Читал такую версию, что ругательство "сволочь" произошло от названия рабочих, занимающихся сволакиванием кораблей по суше. Это правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Русск. сущ. **сволочь** — известно с XIV века (в знач. «сволочённый куда-либо мусор»). Происходит от гл. **волочь**, из праслав. формы *volčiti, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. влачѫ, влачити (др.-греч. ἕλκειν), русск. волочь, волочить. Это разъяснение о слове* сволочь *дано в Викисловаре со ссылкой на словарь Фасмера, хотя в самом словаре (издание 1986 г.) этого слова нет. Версия, которую озвучили вы, тоже связана с глаголом **волочь, волочить**. Сволочь -* прост. устар. *'люди низкого происхождения или положения';* груб. прост.* 'cброд, подлые, скверные люди'.

В Большом толково-фразеологическом словаре Михельсона тоже есть подтверждение этой версии о мусоре: "Сволочь — (иноск. бранн.) дрянной людъ, шатуны, воришки, негодяи, гдѣ либо собравшіеся намекъ на всякую сволочь, въ одно мѣсто (сволоченный) съ поля бороною соръ (траву, бурьянъ и пр.)" (орфография дореволюционная).

В Этимологическом словаре Г.А.Крылова читаем: "Это слово, имеющее значение "мерзавец, негодяй", восходит к той же основе, что и глагол *волочить*; первоначально означало 'мусор, собранный в одно место'".